Ideas to provide a read only archive of old e-mail accounts
We recently had a long term employee leave the company with 30 GB of emails on Google Workspace, because we have merged other leaving employees' mailbox to this last employee.
Long story short, this account is suspended since 2 or 3 months and rarely accessed for archives, so we would like to archive this mailbox instead of keeping this account active or merging potentially 80% of unnecessary emails which will be passed on indefinitely.
The simplest idea I have is to export (Google Export) or download every email in txt format (using Thunderbird or whatever) and point a simple webmail client to it (open-source or we would dev ourself if no other choice). In the case we would dev it ourself, I thought of a simple front with an Sqlite database indexing all the subjects, contents and filenames of every message in the (downloaded) mailbox, then when a user searches for something in the archives, sqlite will answer pretty quickly I suppose.
I'm looking for some suggestions to achieve these "read only" mail archives and if possible, with all the non-merged e-mail accounts together (and not separate accounts with id and passwords for instance). If this kind of solution is not possible, then we will think about creating a simple front with an sqlite database indexing every file and I'm open to suggestions for storage or index if it can stay simple but more optimised.

Maybe you can use something like https://www.epaddproject.org/home
